# Leaflet - map not displaying in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've created a interactive leaflet map, using leaflet-provider.js for tiles, which works great in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, but i'm not able to make it appear in Internet Explorer.

I made a fiddle: [leaflet-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL1p2ukm/)

Thanks anyone for help !

```
'
```

Comment: You are using ES6 syntax, which is [not compatible](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you very much Thibaut. Used Babel to convert. Worked perfectly !